# Spring Boot hosting on Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem with hosting my spring boot application on google cloud App Engine.

I have hosted an app one time successfully in the past as to test how it all works. Now I have made an application that also uses a CloudSQL MySql instance, so its a bit more complex.

Somewhere I got lost along the way: I built the root directory of my project with maven(as before) and deployed the snapshot jar to App engine with "gcloud app deploy _.jar". It says the upload is done, I went to check in the GCP interface. To my surprise I found that it says that this version has size of 0B!!! Needless to say my hosted app doesn't work, I'm not even able to access a hello message which I mapped to the root endpoint "/".

I have absolutely no idea why this is, or even how to start to fix it. Any ideas are appreciated, thanks in advance.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>accessing-data-mysql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>accessing-data-mysql</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share you pom.xml file? There is something wrong with your packaging

Comment: I have edited my post to include the pom.xml. @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy a JAR, you need to deploy a fat jar. Add this build plugin and remove the Spring boot maven plugin (in conflict with the shade plugin)

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>YOUR MAIN CLASS</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Replace `YOUR MAIN CLASS` by the full qualified path of your main class and then deploy on App Engine.